# Adding Role based access control for Admin-On-Rest

Tags: reactjs, redux, admin-on-rest

Am creating an app using Marmelab Admin-On-Rest to create an app to let a team of users edit, graph, schedule, publish and finally track a set of blog posts.

Would like to show custom views to every team based on their role.

Any way to achieve that using Admin-On-Rest? Would ideally like to use default Admin-On-Rest and NOT create my own Redux and React app from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's a fairly common scenario. I'm considering the following solution:

Extend the authClient with a `hasRole` method.

Provide a `withRoles` Higher Order Function taking the `authClient` and an object mapping roles to Views components.

Usage would be:

```js
import React from 'react';

import { simpleRestClient, Admin, Resource } from 'admin-on-rest';
import withRoles from 'aor-roles';

import { PostCreateForTeam1, PostCreateForTeam2 } from './posts';

const App = () => (
    <Admin restClient={simpleRestClient('http://path.to.my.api')}>
        <Resource name="posts" list={PostList} create={
            withRoles(authClient, {
                team1: PostCreateForTeam1,
                team2: PostCreateForTeam2,
            })
        } />
    </Admin>
);

export default App;
```

Where `team1` and `team2` would be roles. It may be interesting that the `authClient.hasRole` can be asynchronous so that it may check the role using an API (I'm thinking about SASS services for auth and roles checks). It may be tricky to correctly handle this.

Give me some days to think about it :)

Edit: Found an API I'm happy with.

authClient would have to manage a new type: `AUTH_GET_ROLE` which would return a promise resolving to the user role.

```js
export const ProductEdit = props => (
    <SwitchRoles authClient={authClient} {...props}>
        <ForRole role="role1">
            <ProductEditRole1 />
        </ForRole>
        <ForRole role="role2">
            <ProductEditRole2 />
        </ForRole>
    </SwitchRoles>
);
```

The `role` prop of the `ForRole` component also accept a function for more complex check.

We just released [aor-permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aor-permissions) !

Comment: I think this might work. will have to extend the Resource Component. Will give it a try and tell you my results. I am quite new to Front End Engineering however :) so my solution may not be very elegant.

Comment: We will release a solution for this very soon, either today or tomorrow. You can already look at it: https://github.com/marmelab/aor-permissions

Comment: Here you go! Let us know what you think :)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/aor-permissions

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to make at least a custom reducer in addition of your authClient. Then make a ForRole component connected with redux and similar to the Responsive component in Admin-on-rest.

Check the role inside it and make it display what's needed for each role

Comment: Hi @Gildas. I see what you mean. I had mistakenly assumed that you meant Responsive as a certain class of components (on github). I think, this might work. I will try and write a custom reducer when I am a bit further into my project and have components ready for my other user categories. Again, thank you so much for your time.

Comment: On further thinking. This ForRole component will have to be passed as a child to the Admin component. I guess I was again not very specific in my question. Looking at the Admin documentation, it does not seem to have the ability to support any component except Resouce. Do you think I can make this work without significant retooling?

Comment: I have been considering this 

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Theming.html#responsive-utility

Would it be possible somehow to do display custom Admin menu based on authenticated role?

Comment: Could not post my very long new answer as a comment so I had to create a new one :)